# Does it Flutter has any docs that describe the different screen size and density?

Tags: flutter, dart, screen-density, pixel-density

I build a small demo app using Flutter and it looks different between iPhone x and android nexus 5x. Does Flutter have any docs that describe the different screen sizes and densities? Also, the AppBar looks different. Any help, please?

[image]

Comment: What kind of information do you think would help you? Screen sizes and density are not specified in Flutter and there is not a limited set of combinations, this information is read from the device.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer my problem is that I need to make same app in iOS and android. I put a picture and it seems something is not right in both devices. Coming from Qt QML I need to ask if such a things exist in Flutter. Do you know any example how to read from device and set the items height or width? thanks

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Creating-Responsive-Apps

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, thank you